# Creating a base controller default action for all ActionResults

Tags: asp.net-mvc, default, actionresult

I'm trying to find out if its possible to create a controller or action result in MVC that will trigger for every action.

Basically I want a check to occur before people are directed to the url each time, if this check fails I will return a different view but I don't want to write this out for every single action in my controller.

Can this be done??

Comment: which framework are you using??

Comment: Ah, I have it now thanks.
Custom ActionFilterAttribute can handle it for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a custom ActionFilterAttribute.
Overriding OnActionExecuting means I can put the same check in for all actions.